# How many missions/levels are available in campaign mode?

Tags: factorio

I have played the 'tutorial' mission and it was quite fun! I bought the game and started the next mission (campaign mode). I'm at level 2 now and wonder how many levels exist in the current Version(0.9.8)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factorio currently comes with two campaigns, "First Steps" (3 levels, the tutorial) and "New Hope" (4 levels), for a total of 7 levels. (Internally, these are called "demo" and "beta".)

It also has the Scenario Pack, which contains two more "side campaigns", Transport Belt Madness (3 levels) and Tight Spot (5 levels) -- giving you a grand total of 15 levels.

Comment: Two years later, is this answer still up-to-date?

Comment: @Kyralessa unless I am missing something, I see four campaigns in 0.13.1: "first steps," "new hope," "transport belt madness," and "tight spot."

Comment: @Snowman, but how many missions in each one?

Comment: @Kyralessa not sure, I have only played the regular game, not any campaigns. But clearly there have been changes in this area since the answer was posted.

Comment: @Kyralessa It's still up to date.

Comment: @Snowman The "demo" and "beta" campaigns are called "First Steps" and "New Hope" in the campaign UI, but are the same campaigns mentioned in my original answer. The content of the missions has changed somewhat as more features are added to the game, but no new missions have been added.

Comment: @ToxicFrog good to know. It would be worth updating your answer so the names accurately reflect the current state of the game, then.